# In Python check if current time is less than specific time?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

In a Python script I want it to check before executing if it's before 9AM UTC so that it can do something specific.

I was wondering what the best way to do this is in terms of checking the time to ensure it's before 9AM each day the script is run? Keeping in mind that the code could be running on different machines that have different timezones.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `23:59` is too late but `00:01` is ok because it is before `9am`?

Comment: Yeah so anything between 00:00 and 08:59 is ok but anything between 9:00 and 23:59 is not ok.

Comment: unrelated: [it is best to use half-open intervals in programming](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html) e.g., `[00:00, 9:00)` (including `00:00`, excluding `9:00`).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module should be very helpful for you.  Try something like the following:

```
>>> d = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
>>> print d
2015-06-17 11:39:48.585000
>>> d.hour
11
>>> if d.hour < 9:
        print "Run your code here"
# nothing happens, it's after 9:00 here.
>>>
```

Comment: But d is time for a particular time zone, so convert to UTC by `now_UTC = datetime.now(timezone('UTC'))`

Comment: alternatively, use `datetime.datetime.utcnow()`

Comment: Thanks Matthew.  I couldn't remember the exact method name for `utcnow`, so I was going to edit it in as soon as I found it.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try this

In all computers convert time to UTC and then compare it with the time you want to start

```
from datetime import datetime

now_UTC = datetime.utcnow() # Get the UTC time

# check for the condition
if(now_UTC.hour < 9):
    do something()
```

Answer (score 0):

From reading up online I have come up with this answer which I doesn't look like the most efficient but seems to do the job:

```
import datetime
import pytz

utc = pytz.utc
loc_dt = utc.localize(datetime.datetime.today().replace(hour=9, minute=0))

today = utc.localize(datetime.datetime.today())

if loc_dt < today:
    print("Go")
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the current hour in UTC:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.gmtime().tm_hour
15
```